# How do I pause the entire script for a set amount of time in javascript? Is that even possible?

Tags: javascript, wait

I need pause my script to allow a wait between events in my game. If anyone could explain how I could do this, in simple terms (because I am a newbie), I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your entire game needs a "game loop" that doesnt "pause" but just stops doing things. Look into "step tasking". ...... Some code (in your question) would be nice to put it all in context.

Comment: When it comes to "pausing" a javascript script, think about it -- if you were to somehow entirely "pause" a script, how would you be able to "unpause" the script if the script were completely paused? Whereas if you just use `setTimeout`, instead of "pausing" code you are simply delaying the code, which is definitely what you're looking for here.

Comment: @cannicide - some languages like python have a time.sleep() function which will cause the everything to pause for a set amount of time.

Comment: See @Petro below for the concept of a "game loop" and "step tasking". A "pause" would be *not* running the update, at least those parts affecting active game play. A menu could still run during pause for example, with if conditions.

Comment: You may Need a variable, that, If set to true does prevent things from going ahead. Then you could use setTimeout to set ist to false and thus get your game back running. It’s some If-Statements more, but you can control what should be paused and what not.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you'd want a loop to control timing in your game for "pauses", which would just be iterations of the loop. Think of FPS in a game and how each cycle it will draw something new.

[Here's a very simple example:](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript/)

```
function update(progress) {
  // Update the state of the world for the elapsed time since last render
}

function draw() {
  // Draw the state of the world
}

function loop(timestamp) {
  var progress = timestamp - lastRender

  //you would call your functions here when the game is "running":
  update(progress)
  draw()

  lastRender = timestamp
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
var lastRender = 0
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

SetInterval will call your function everytime a fix interval of time passes. Like a clock.

[SetInterval tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

SetTimeout will call a function, only once, after a set amount of time passes.

[SetTimeout tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is the way to go.

Usage example:

```js
console.log('before')
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('after - 500ms later')
}, 500)
console.log('still before')
```

setTimeout won't pause javascript, there's no way to do that. Instead, it'll schedule a function to be called at some point in the future. This is why when you run the code snippet, you'll see "before" and "still before" get logged at the same time. Only the contents in the function passed into setTimeout() will happen after the delay provided.

Note that this means that there is no way to return a value from the setTimeout call for usage afterwards - this is something that many newcomers struggle with when they're first trying to work with async logic (like setTimeout). *everything* that you want to happen after this delay has to be put inside the setTimeout function (or, you can of course call other functions from it if you feel like your function is starting to get a little big).